# Linux Assembly reference

Tags: linux, assembly, reference

I am reading the book "Professional Assembly Language", with sample code written for Intel IA-32 processors. Assembler used is GNU Assembler. Where can I find this Assembly reference? For example, writing Assembly for Windows, I can find the reference in Intel WEB site. What about Linux and GNU Assembler?

Comment: Did you try wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler and the resources therein?

Comment: The default syntax is known as AT&T syntax if that helps you google it. IIRC `as` has a switch to accept Intex syntax instead, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia references this: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/

Answer (score 2):

Assembler only depends on the CPU, not the OS. So the documents on the Intel side are what you're looking for.

If you want to call OS functions, you must read the compiler ABI documents (which explain how to pass arguments and how the return value is handled). Plus you need a list of functions which you can find in the man pages of your Linux box.

To get you started, I suggest to compile a program in high-level language like C into assembler to see what happens. Just invoke `gcc -S file.c` instead of `gcc -c file.c`.

Comment: True but how is that related to the question or my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here:
http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html

from here:
http://www.gnu.org/manual/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a book on Intel IA 32 then you should try grabbing the instruction set manuals from Intel's  site
http://developer.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm
I think you will this as a complete reference for instruction .

Also the assembly language reference for linux and windows will be same if they are installed on the same architecture , as assembly language depends upon the architecture.Use intels instruction set reference if you are using an intel CPU.

For the syntax of your assembler well you should check the manual accompanying it for gnu

http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/